# iOS - Creating Deletable UILabels on any UIView Such as

Tags: ios, uiview, uilabel

Good Afternoon,

I am trying to create deletable UILabels so that my users can delete the labels that have been added on top of their photo.

Just like the label you see below on top of the photo, but with a small delete (or more commonly an 'x') button at the top-right corner of the label.

This image does not belong to me. It comes straight from the [Quick - add text to photos fast](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/quick-add-text-to-photos-fast/id574443485?mt=8) app on the iOS app store.

[image]

How can I accomplish this? Would it be best just to create a UIView with a label and a button? I feel this is the best way, but want to be efficient in my work.

I hope everyone had a great weekend, thanks!

Comment: I think what you've described is a great solution. Follows the KISS principle.

Comment: @justColbs. Create on UILabel and show it when viewDidLoad and hide it when button click.